# ”En” before its reference

Tags: pronoms, en

There’s seems to be a type of sentence, such as

> Au sein de ce flux perpétuel, il y **en** a **des forces «actives»**

where ”en” is used directly before its reference (”des forces «actives»”): what is the rôle of this seemingly pleonastic ”en”? Is it stylistic or does it make a difference in sense compared to leaving it out? When to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are missing a bit of context here, but as I understand, It is a way to insist there are some *forces "actives"*, not just any type of *force*.

I suppose several types of forces were mentioned earlier in the text/speech, then "active" ones and it's a way to insist on those latter ones being present in this *flux perpétuel*.

One could have also said :

> - (...), il y bien des forces "actives" .
> - (...), il y a effectivement des forces "actives".

I must say it's a "spoken style" sentence, and depending on the intonation of speaker, it could also imply there are **a lot** of active forces.

Compared to the original sentence, a non-pleonastic variant looks like a plain boring description to me (physics school book's style) :

> Au sein de ce flux perpétuel, il y a des forces "actives".

Comment: Interesting! That fits the informal context (that I should have included in the question), since it came from a user’s book review on Amazon. It makes a lot of sense to think of the ”en” as adding ”insistance”!